# Plugin for Eclipse IDE to check language grammar

Tags: eclipse

I'm, looking for a plugin (or some kind of extension) for the Eclipse IDE so it can check grammar, and flag mistakes like "The dog dog is lost" etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a tool called [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/) for grammar check in the past.  It's an excellent free proofreading software for grammar, style, and spell checking.  It also has a [list of addons](http://wiki.languagetool.org/software-that-supports-languagetool-as-a-plug-in-or-add-on) supporting Eclipse.  The original author and the addon listed on the LanguageTool wiki is deprecated, but linked below is a fork that is said to be the successor.

*Note: I have not used this plugin, however, I have used LanguageTool*

> ## [languagetool-eclipse-plugin](https://github.com/vogellacompany/languagetool-eclipse-plugin)
>
> #### Eclipse plug-in for Languagetools
>
> This plugin contains an Eclipse plug-in to use the spell checking engine LanguageTool in the Eclipse IDE. This repository started of as a fork of https://github.com/auguster/languagetool-eclipse-plugin but as the original remote included the languagetools JARs it was recreated from scratch.

[image: Grammar check using OP's test text]

*This is a screenshot from the website, which should implement the same check in the addon*

Comment: Thanks very much, but even for the replacement eclipse plugin the update site is broken, and it doesn't seem possible to get this up and running in any logical way